# Wordpress: is_single not applying to post types

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Wordpress: is_single not applying to post types

Hi all,

Ive got a standard blog template that is using post types: gallery, video, audio, and quote, in addition to the standard. I have a content.php that instructs the handling of each type in general. For single post display, I have a template part loading that should handle what I think is all single posts, but in reality is only applying to standard single posts and excluding single gallery, video, audio and quote posts. (The content-single template assigns a "related posts" function and others that don't display in a blog posts list, which i want visible on all single posts regardless of type)

I've tried is_single ('post types' ) )  and is_singular( array ('post_type1' etc) ) in addition to the standard is_single () ) ; ...

I've been through the codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Post_Page) and I've seen blog posts on how to assign different templates to different post types such as http://gabrieleromanato.name/wordpress-create-a-different-single-php-template-for-each-post-format/,  but I'm the opposite: I want is_single to apply to all post types: standard, video, audio, gallery and quote. I tried the method suggested here [Wordpress Conditional if is_single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044568/wordpress-conditional-if-is-single) about creating individual template parts for each post type (by making duplicates of content-single named single-video, single-audio etc) but that didn't work either.

I know I'm dumb. Thanks in advance for any advice you might have.

```
<?php elseif (is_single( ) ) : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content-single'); ?>

<?php else : ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
    <div id="entry-category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
    <div id="entry-title"><?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?></div><!--- .entry-title -->
<div id="entry-date"><?php the_time('l, jS F Y');?></div><!-- .entry-meta -->

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="post-header">

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        the_content(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because Post Type is not `is_single()` - it is `is_singular()`
You can read more about is [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)

Answer (score 0):

for custom post types use `is_singular()`

```
<?php elseif (is_singular('your_post_type_name') ) : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content-single'); ?>

<?php else : ?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
    <div id="entry-category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
    <div id="entry-title"><?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?></div><!--- .entry-title -->
<div id="entry-date"><?php the_time('l, jS F Y');?></div><!-- .entry-meta -->

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="post-header">

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        the_content(); ?>
```